# Count the frequency of strings found (in any order) in another column and return result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the count of words (strings) in a pandas dataframe column that are found in another column in any order.

I've tried the following, which is close, but it doesn't count the occurrences (It only tells me if the words were found in any order).

```
words='|'.join(df['Cluster Name'].unique())
df['frequency']=df['Keyword'].str.contains(words).astype(int)
```

Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
data = {'Keyword' : ['Nike', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Stripy Socks', 'Socks Nike', 'Adidas Socks'],
        'Cluster' : ['Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

expected output

```
              Keyword     Cluster Frequency
0                Nike  Nike Socks         1
1          Nike Socks  Nike Socks         2
2  Nike Stripy Socks   Nike Socks         2
3          Socks Nike  Nike Socks         2
4        Adidas Socks  Nike Socks         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function that takes a row as an input, and then `apply` it to the dataframe rowwise using the argument `axis=1`:

```
def count_keywords(row):
    freq = 0
    for word in row['Keyword'].split(" "):
        if word in row['Cluster']:
            freq += 1
    return freq

df['Frequency'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_keywords(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             Keyword     Cluster  Frequency
0               Nike  Nike Socks          1
1         Nike Socks  Nike Socks          2
2  Nike Stripy Socks  Nike Socks          2
3         Socks Nike  Nike Socks          2
4       Adidas Socks  Nike Socks          1
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to @Derek, but it will work properly if the words in `Cluster` column are separated not only with whitespases

```
from re import findall
import pandas as pd

def count_corresponding(row):
    keywords = row.Keyword.split(' ')
    count = sum([len(findall(keyword,row.Cluster)) for keyword in keywords])
    return count


data = {'Keyword' : ['Nike', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Stripy Socks', 'Socks Nike', 'Adidas Socks'],
        'Cluster' : ['Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks', 'Nike Socks']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Frequency'] = df.apply(count_corresponding, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `explode` then count the occurrence for word , then `sum` the back

```
x = df.assign(Keyword = df.Keyword.str.split(' ')).explode('Keyword')
df['freq'] = x.apply(lambda y : y['Keyword'] in y['Cluster'],axis=1).groupby(level=0).sum()
df
             Keyword     Cluster  freq
0               Nike  Nike Socks     1
1         Nike Socks  Nike Socks     2
2  Nike Stripy Socks  Nike Socks     2
3         Socks Nike  Nike Socks     2
4       Adidas Socks  Nike Socks     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use `apply` anyway, so you can directly use `set` intersection:

```
df['Frequency'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x['Keyword'].split()).intersection(x['Cluster'].split())), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
             Keyword     Cluster  Frequency
0               Nike  Nike Socks          1
1         Nike Socks  Nike Socks          2
2  Nike Stripy Socks  Nike Socks          2
3         Socks Nike  Nike Socks          2
4       Adidas Socks  Nike Socks          1
```